# Find the closure for several sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

(a) $\mathbb{Q}$

(b) {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy<1$}

(c) {$(x,\sin($${1}\over{x}$$)):x>0$}

(d) {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2:x^2+y^2<1$}

---

First Closure $\overline{A}$, it is a set contains all the limit points

So $\overline{A} = int{A} \cup \partial {A}$

(a) Closure is just all the $\mathbb{Q}$, because put all $\mathbb{Q}$ on the number line will form a continuous line with many dots on it. Ever single dot is the interior but also the limit point itself

(b) I only know how to try a graph but fail to describe it. Its the area of (under the curve of first quadrant and about the curve of the third quadrant and the total area of the second and third quadrant) on a $xy$ plane is the interior. Boundary is $xy=1$

(c) It is just an irregular oscillating sine curve on the positive x axis where origin is not included. But whats the boundary?

(d) Interior is the numerous dots inside the unit circle ($x^2+y^2=1$). boundary is the perimeter itself

Please help guys, thanks!!

Comment: For c), draw the curve or have software draw it for you. Can you see that every point on the line segment that joins $(0,1)$ to $(0,-1)$ is awfully close to some points on the curve?

Comment: I drew $y=\sin\frac{1}{x}$ it just every point oscillating from $-1$ to $1$ and get crowded near the origin

Comment: What I was trying to lead you to is that the closure is the collection of all points on the curve, together with the (closed) interval from the point $(0,-1)$ to the point $(0.1)$